# Hypothesis Testing Multiple regression with dummys and interaction

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, categorical-data, interaction

I have a model $$Y_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} *P_i + \beta_{2}*B_i + \beta_{3}*E_i + \beta_{4}*B_i*E_i+u_i$$

where Y is a Rating, P is the price, E is the educationional level ( 0 no higher education; 1 higher education) and B is the specific brand( 0 no brand; 1 product with brand).

Now I should test the hypothesis: " a person with no higher education does not care about the brand"

Then our professor performed a Walch test with the $H_{0}: \beta_{2}=\beta_{3}, \beta_{4}=0$. But I do not get why - could please somebody give me a hint I will write my exam tomorrow and I do not understand how to get this testing problem. Why do I test if the interaction effect equals 0 und the effects of Price and Brand are equal? For me it would be more logical to test if $\beta_{2}=0$ since for a person with no higher education it follows that $E=0$ and, thus, $\beta_{3}*E + \beta_{4}*B*E =0$.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, what he wants to test is whether there is any difference at all between a person with and without higher education. Thus, you need to compare, between each education level, whether brand matters.

Also, I think you are confused about the notation.

In the expression $$Y_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} *P_i + \beta_{2}*B_i + \beta_{3}*E_i + \beta_{4}*B_i*E_i+u_i$$, the coefficient pertaining to the no-education group and and no brand is given by the constant $\beta_0$, $\beta_2$ gives the extra valuation for the product with a brand irrespective of the education level , $\beta_3$ gives the extra valuation for the product from people with higher education irrespective of whether the product has a brand or not and $\beta_4$ gives the extra valuation for the product with a brand from people with higher education.

Thus, if you want to check the effect of higher education on the product, you need to test whether people with higher education evaluate the product differently irrespective of it being branded *and* whether people with higher education evaluate the product with brand differently.

Thus, I would test $H_0:\beta_3=0,\beta_4=0$. What your professor tests is whether brand and education have the same effect on valuation.

I do realize that this does not help you decide if your professor is wrong, but at least it helps you realize that what you suggest is.

[image]
Notice also that the above expression is equivalent to :
$$Y_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} *P_i + \beta_{2}*(B_i=1)*(E_i=0) + \beta_{3}*(B_i=1)*(E_i=1) + \beta_{4}*(B_i=0)*(E_i=1)+u_i$$

In that case, $\beta_0$ gives the valuation for the group $B_i=0,E_i=0$,
$\beta_2$ gives the extra valuation for the group $B_i=1,E_i=0$,
$\beta_3$ gives the extra valuation for the group $B_i=1,E_i=1$,
$\beta_4$ gives the extra valuation for the group $B_i=0,E_i=1$.

In that case,the Venn diagram becomes

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. You really helped me and I think I understand it now - your test seems far more logical. I may visit him today and ask him about this.

Comment: @Methamortix but please don't quote me ;)

It would be interesting to have his answer here.

Comment: One last question: then the H_a would be : $H_{a}: \beta_{3} \ne 0  \lor \beta_{4} \ne 0 $

Comment: @Methamortix Yes, unless you have a theoretical reason why you should test for inequalities.